# Creating a search function to search a Sequel Databse using a 'GET' method

Tags: javascript, ruby, database, search, sequel

I have an `index.erb` file created and within that file, I have code for a search bar:

```
<nav>
  <div class="nav-wrapper">
    <form>
      <div class="input-field">
        <input id="search" type="search" placeholder="Search..." required>
        <label for="search"><i class="mdi-action-search"></i></label>
        <i class="mdi-navigation-close"></i>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Ultimately I want to have this search bar to search my Sequel Database. I want to use a GET method in my `app.rb` file. However, I have a few obstacles.

**Part 1**
How can I save the text (that the user types into my search bar) into a variable that I can then use in my GET method (within my `app.rb` file)? In other words, how do I save what the user types into the search bar?

**Part 2**
Within my `app.rb` file, does it matter what my get method is called?

**Part 3**
I want to search my database using the `.where()` method. In my `model.rb` file, I defined a class `Town`. Within that migration, I have a collection of data. I want to search that data. So I'm guessing that my code in the `app.rb` file would be something like this (?):

```
@towns = Town.where(:name => @variable_from_part1)
```

Using the variable from PART 1 of my question, how would I go about searching my Sequel database? In other words, how would I search the database for what the user typed in and then display the result on my page?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**PART 1**
You create a `name` attribute within the `<input/>` field. So it would look something like this:

```
<input name="search" type="text" placeholder="Search..."/>
```

The most basic way of submitting this input is with an input field where the `type=sumbit`

```
<input type="submit" value="Search"/>
```

**PART 2**
It doesn't matter what you call the GET method. You could search a database using one, two, etc. methods. One way of doing it is to have a `get '/search' do` (or something like that) that directs the user to a webpage with the search bar. Then you could have that search bars `action` equal a different root like `get '/' do`. You could also just do it all under one GET root.

**PART 3**
Then within the `app.rb` file, under the GET root (`get '/' do`), you would use `params[:search]` to save the text that was entered into your input field.

```
get '/' do
    @towns = Town.where(:name => params[:search])
end
```